# Error in Swift with method loadJSONFromBundle

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I'm getting an error:

> Type 'Dictionary' has no member loadJSONFromBundle.

Any idea what's wrong with it?

```
init(filename: String) 
{
    if let dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.loadJSONFromBundle(filename) {
        if let tilesArray = dictionary["tiles"] as? [[Int]] {
            for (row, rowArray) in enumerate(tilesArray as! [[Int]]) {
                let tileRow = NumRows - row - 1
                for (column, value) in enumerate(rowArray) {
                    if value == 1 {
                        tiles[column, tileRow] = Tile()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such method as `loadJSONFromBundle`. Where do you see such a method documented?

Answer (score 0):

`.loadJSONFromBundle` is not a default method in Dictionary. This can be added by extending Dictionary. Here my implementation in Swift 3:

```
import Foundation

extension Dictionary {
    static func loadJSONFromBundle(filename: String) -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "json") {
            var error: NSError?
            do {
                let data: NSData? = try NSData(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
                if let data = data {
                    let dict: Any? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
                    if let dict = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        return dict
                    }
                    else {
                        print("file '\(filename)' is not vaild JSON: \(error!)")
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("could not load file '\(filename)'")
                return nil
            }
        }
        else {
            print("could not find level file '\(filename)'")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```